# Save a copy of a field before updating it on Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following document structure:

```
currencies[
    {
        value: 0.00012,
        last: 0.00013
    },
...]
```

I am using an external service to get the new rates of each currency. But before updating `value` I want to move its value to `last` field so I have a "backup" of the last value before the updates.

What I have done so far is updating `value` field succesfuly. But I don't have any idea of how to move `value` to `last` before updating in the same transaction.

```
db.collection("currencies")
            .doc('USD')
            .set({ value: newRates['USD'] })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.log(error);
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to read the existing value and then update it back in the `last` field. There isn't any method to do this in single go.

```js
const docRef = db.collection("currencies").doc('USD')

const curValue = (await docRef.get()).data().value

await docRef.update({value: "newValue", last: curValue})
```

Comment: Really there isn't any way to reference to `this.value` inside `.set(...)` clause?

Comment: @E.Williams no. `set()` only accepts an object that should be added in the document.

Comment: I recommend doing this in a transaction, instead of a separate `get` and `set` as you set yourself up for accidental overwrites without that.